# dc input base must be a number between 2 and 16 inclusive

Tags: linux, sed, hex, dc

Called with `./dice.sh 1 1 1 1`

I get `dc input base must be a number between 2 and 16 inclusive`

```
vim dice.sh
dice=0$(echo $* | tr -d [:space:] | tr 1-6 0-5)
eval "hex=$(dc -e 16o6i${dice}p)"

# Print the last 64 hex digits of the output:
echo $hex | sed -e 's/.*\(.\{64\}\)$/\1/'
```

Why is this error occurring? I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is your input and expected output?  Why do you need `eval`?

Comment: Strip it down to just the call to `dc` and then just debug that without having to dig through all of the surrounding fluff.

Comment: @codeforester https://github.com/swansontec/dice2key/blob/master/dice2key.sh
Ok Ed, I will look at that